# mvn integration-test doesn't execute cucumber integration tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, selenium, maven, cucumber

### Problem

I have a project with unit tests and integration tests with selenium.

When I execute cucumber integration test with IntelliJ it works well as you can see:

[Cucumber integration tests executed with Intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwyAl.png)

But, when I execute mvn integration-test, It seems that maven-failsafe-plugin doesn't find any integration test:

[Failsafe output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mu3aB.png)

### Project information

- I defined the follow POM:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.weblogism.cucumberjvm</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-example</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>Cucumber-jvm Java Example</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <cucumber.plugin>pretty</cucumber.plugin>
    <cucumber.filter.tags>@wip</cucumber.filter.tags>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
      <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.6.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
      <version>5.6.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
      <version>5.6.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.picocontainer</groupId>
      <artifactId>picocontainer</artifactId>
      <version>2.15</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>cuke-jvm-example</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-java</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <requireJavaVersion>
                  <version>1.8.0</version>
                </requireJavaVersion>
              </rules>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>18</source>
          <target>18</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-test-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>src/it/java</source>
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>add-resource</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <resources>
                <resource>
                  <directory>src/it/resources</directory>
                </resource>
              </resources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>


      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <failIfNoTests>true</failIfNoTests>
              <systemPropertyVariables>
                <cucumber.plugin>${cucumber.plugin}</cucumber.plugin>
                <cucumber.filter.tags>${cucumber.filter.tags}</cucumber.filter.tags>
              </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>pre-integration-test</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>post-integration-test</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

- The folders structure is
  [Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXRJi.png)
- mvn integration-test output
  https://drive.google.com/file/d/19PlmIvX7AN45DviOaQeB0dyB7jYsI05E/view?usp=sharing
- I'm using spring-boot-maven-plugin to start/end server at start/end integration-test
- I'm using build-helper-maven-plugin to get the it folder sources, where integration-test are defined

Answer (score 1):

By using `cucumber-junit` you are running Cucumber through JUnit 4, however Spring Boot 2.7 uses JUnit 5 and no longer includes `junit-vintage` by default. As a result JUnit 4 test are not executed.

Consider either using the [`cucumber-junit-platform-engine`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/junit-platform-engine) or adding `junit-vintage`.